# TypeError: func.apply is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, use-effect

I'm trying to use useEffect function like that:

```
    const [data, setData] = useState({ courses: [] });
    
    useEffect(async () => {
        const result = await axios.get(
            "http://example.com/api/v1/categories/"
        );
    
        await setData(result.data);
    }, []);
    
    console.log(data);

return (
    <div>
        <div>{data.info1}</div>
        <div>{data.info2}</div>
        <div>{data.info3}</div>
        <div>{data.info4}</div>
    </div>
);
```

But when I try to use `data` variable it sometimes throws this error:

```
TypeError: func.apply is not a function
HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback
C:/asdasd/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:188
  185 |     window.event = windowEvent;
  186 |   }
  187 | 
> 188 |   func.apply(context, funcArgs);
      | ^  189 |   didError = false;
  190 | } // Create a global error event handler. We use this to capture the value
  191 | // that was thrown. It's possible that this error handler will fire more
```

I don't know, where do I miss.

Comment: please post your code that has this line `func.apply(context, funcArgs);`

Comment: Effects are supposed to return a cleanup **function** or nothing at all. [See the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) Your `async function` returns a Promise. So `returnedPromise.apply(...)` will obviously fail.

Comment: Does the same apply when I call `my_asyn_function().then(()=>{...})`?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You **can only pass a normal function as argument to useEffect**, and not an async function. In order to use async await in useEffect, you can write your function as an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression - you write the function and call it immediately).

```
const [data, setData] = useState({ courses: [] });
    
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        const result = await axios.get(
            "http://example.com/api/v1/categories/"
        );
        setData(result.data);
    })();
}, []);
    
console.log(data);

return (
    <div>
        <div>{data.info1}</div>
        <div>{data.info2}</div>
        <div>{data.info3}</div>
        <div>{data.info4}</div>
    </div>
);
```

Or you can just create a normal named async function and then call it as below,

```
const [data, setData] = useState({ courses: [] });
    
useEffect(() => {
    const getResult = async () => {
        const result = await axios.get(
            "http://example.com/api/v1/categories/"
        );
        setData(result.data);
    };

    getResult();
}, []);

.
.
.
```

Comment: Ohh, I'm sorry. Your first method works fine. Thanks

Comment: @Kenny, Is it something related to react version? Because In my project in which react version is 17 useEffect(async () => {},[]) is working but the project in which version 16 is there useEffect(async() => {},[]) not working. Throwing this func.apply not function error

Comment: Oh that is interesting @JaynaTanawala. I cannot see anything in the docs which suggests that async function is required!

Answer (score 3):

This indicates that you're returning a value from useEffect that isn't a function.
Looking at the code that you shared you're using async functions with useEffect a lot, which isn't supported and will trigger this error.

Can you provide more code ,so can I understand what you are trying to do!

Answer (score 2):

Please do not use async await, {} and [] in useEffect. solve for me

```
useEffect(() => {
    props.actions.something();
}, [])
```

if you have use

```
useEffect(async () => 
  await props.actions.something();
)
```

Comment: this fixed my issue too, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

you may write an async function separately and then call it from inside

Comment: async function myFunc(data) {}

useEffect(() => {
  myFunc(data);
}, [data]);

Answer (score 0):

Remove return keyword which is written in useEffect resolve my issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while generating the random number with Math interface and by mistake I had put () parentheses after Math interface like

```
const randomNum = Math().random()
```

So, after removing () parentheses it worked

```
const randomNum = Math.random()
```