# Noob UseEffect problems

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-hooks

I'm trying to display a page(let's call it /abc) based on a promise response (true o false), so i discovered that is possible using usestate and useeffect, it look like it almost works /abc is displayed correctly but i have 2 problems:

1. when i refresh the page, if the value was true after the refresh it came back false, if it was false and i refresh it came back false as
   it shoud be, but when i came to /abc from another page it works as intended.
2. when i switch from another page to /abc everything is fine but when i switch from /abc to another page i got `react-dom.development.js:188 Uncaught TypeError: func.apply is not a function` i found out that is something related to the fact that
   useEffect can not return something that isn't a function, but i
   don't really understand how to make it work.

This is the code:

```
const [data, setData] = useState(null);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

async function doSomething() {
 let result = await writeContracts && writeContracts.Whitelist.isWhitelisted(address);
   return result  // result is the promise 
 }

async function test(){
  var isWhitelisted = await doSomething()
  if (isWhitelisted == true){
    return true
  }else{       
    return false}
}


useEffect(async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);

      const dat = await test();
      setData(dat);

      setLoading(false);
    }
}, []);
```

Then

```
if(loading) {return (
  <span>Loading</span> )};
if (data == false ){ return ( 
  <div>False</div> )};
else { return (
  <div>True</div> )};
```

I know that the logic about how to get the promise value is probably wrong (as probably everything here is wrong) but I spent hours to try to understand how to get the promise response alone and calling the function inside another function was the only thing that returned me just true or false, and more hours trying to figure how this hooks works.

Comment: You do have a problem with your useEffect - you can find the solution you need here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63570597/typeerror-func-apply-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I know, async `useEffect` is an antipattern. You should refactor your code avoiding this. Something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchMyAPI() {
      const dat = await test();
      setData(dat);
    }

    try {
       setLoading(true);
       fetchMyAPI();
       setLoading(false);
    }
}, []);
```

Comment: Thankyou!!! it resolved the main problem<3 any idea about the fact that when i refresh the page the value became false even if it's true ?

Comment: @Amnesia420 I found [this](https://dev.to/danialdezfouli/what-s-wrong-with-the-async-function-in-useeffect-4jne) intersting article that explains why async `useEffect` is an antipattern. Read it, is really clear =)

Answer (score 0):

Please go through it you will get it easily
I have created a sample application for you
https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-sea-k58x3?file=/src/App.js:0-821

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import axios from "axios";

export default function App() {
  //state for storing the data
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  //calling api for data
  const getUserData = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    let response = await axios.get(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
    );
    setLoading(false);
    setData(response.data);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getUserData();
  }, []);
  //function for maping API Data
  const displayUserData = () => {
    return data.map((item) => {
      return (
        <ul>
          <li>{item.title}</li>
        </ul>
      );
    });
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">{loading ? <p>Loading</p> : displayUserData()}</div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This way of making the useEffect as an `async` function is anti-pattern as the [cleanup function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) won't execute. One way is to have an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) inside the `useEffect()` hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        try {
          setLoading(true);
          const dat = await test();
          setData(dat);
          setLoading(false);
        }
    })();
}, []);
```

The second method would be to define the async function inside the `useEffect()` hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getResult = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        const dat = await test();
        setData(dat);
        setLoading(false);
    };

    getResult();

}, []);
```